# I wonder why some have inputs and some don't in Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

Whenever I study the Kalman filter. I saw two kind of algorithms of Kalman filter.
One has an input matrix, the other don't have input matrix.
So I'm always confused by that.
Let me know what is the difference.
Please.....

[image: With an input matrix]

---

[image: Without an input matrix]

Comment: The two images look identical to me

Answer (score 2):

The 'inputs' are often called 'controls' and that is a typical case. For example if the system was a car, u might represent the position of the steering wheel, the position of the accelerator and so on. These do not help to determine the position, but they do help when predicting the new state from the old. In some cases the kalman filter may be part of a larger system that actually produces these control signals.

However one may not have access to such information. For example if one was estimating the position (and so on) of a car externally, for example using radar readings, the state of the car controls may be unknown, and so cannot be included.

Note that there is another difference between the two images, and that is the occurrence (in the input case) of a matrix Q that is added to the predicted state covariance. This is not related to the presence of the inputs and indeed I think that its omission from the no-input case is a mistake. Without such a term the state error covariance matrix will collapse over time to 0 and the filter will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Second image is not a good representation of the Kalman Filter. Like dmuir said, initialization process is basically giving information about current states to the filter. In linear case, initial state condition errors are tolerable whereas in nonlinear case, ie. Extended KF which is the most used case of kalman filter, initial conditions are very important. Most the time if you cannot initialize your filter with close approximation of the real initial state, your filter will mostly diverge.

But it looks like you need to restudy whole filter again. I would suggest this site which helped me through Msc greatly.[How Kalman Filters Work](http://www.anuncommonlab.com/articles/how-kalman-filters-work/)